# Laravel query using existing model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've got two models: Offers and Speciality with many to many relatioship:

in Offer.php

```
public function specialities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Speciality');
}
```

in Speciality.php

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class);
}
```

this is simple so far.

Now, I'm building query to get only Offers with certain speciality. The problem is that I'm using `when` helper function, so I don't know how to access speciality model:

```
public function template($person = "", $speciality = "")
{
      $offers = Offer::when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
        return $query->specialities()->where('speciality_name', $speciality)->get();
      })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);
}
```

And this is not working for me. Can anyone give me a tip how should I write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
$offers = Offer::when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
    $query->whereHas('specialities', function($query) use($speciality) {
        $query->where('speciality_name', $speciality);
    });
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: that's the right answer, thank you. Huge thanks also for @acabala for his help for solving this issue +1

Answer (score 2):

For querying you should use `join` instead `specialities()` relation, 
so it will look more like:

```
 $offers = Offer:join('offer_specialities os', 'offer.id', 'os.offer_id')
 ->join('specialities', 'specialities.id', 'os.speciality_id')
 ->when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
    return $query->where('specialities.speciality_name', $speciality)->get();
  })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm not familiar with manual joining multiple tables (there I have pivot table offer_speciality) and when I've got model already configured, I want to use it...

Comment: then try something like this one: `$offers = Offer::with('specialities')->when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
        return $query->where('speciality_name', $speciality)->get();
      })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);` 
(adding **with** to your primary query).

Comment: this gives me unknown collumn (after added with('specialities'))

Comment: Is `speciality_name` correct column name? Maybe you have just `name`, so then it will be `speciality.name`

Comment: I'm putting the correct column name, and it seems that this `with('specialities')` solution does not work

Comment: sure, I'm using number, not name as a field inside speciality table:
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'number' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `offers` where `number` = pl2)",

Comment: $offers = Offer::with('specialities')
          ->when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
            return $query->where('number', $speciality)->get();
          })
          ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);

Comment: Indeed, `with` makes a separate query, so there is no column in this what you are working with :( Then the only solution that comes to me is adding `join` query.

Comment: I'm trying:           $offers = Offer::join('offer_speciality', 'offers.id', 'offer_speciality.offer_id')
          ->join('specialities', 'offer_speciality.speciality_id', 'specialities.id')
          ->when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
            return $query->where('specialities.number', $speciality)->get();
          })
          ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9); 
but it gives me: Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

Comment: I've got always problems with php and sql queries

Comment: remove `->get()` from inner function (you also don't need it in main query, as `paginate()` will do the same.

Comment: I see now it's working, but now I cannot access other models from $offers, lol, I really struggle with php....

Comment: Isn't it because paginator packs your results? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Comment: no it's because you have to use eloquent from start to finish to make it work